# Does lockdown mean lockout? What's the difference between lockout and lockdown?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

Lockdown

An emergency impacting a school campus that prevents the safe evacuation of a school building and requires steps to shelter
students and staff from danger. Lockdown procedures may also be used to ensure the safety of students when an incident occurs
in the vicinity of a school.

Lockout

It is used to secure the school or building from a potential
threat taking place outside, such as law enforcement activity in the
neighborhood. During a lockout, access to the building is restricted, but
there may be controlled limited movement.

Comment: 'Lockdown' --no one goes _in or out_. 'Lockout' --no one comes _in_.

Comment: When asking questions like this, include your dictionary research in the question.

Comment: A lockout is also a tool by employers (especially owners of sports teams) to prevent labor from working. It's like the reverse of a strike.

Answer (score 1):

A lockout locks people out.

A lockdown locks some people in and some people out. If you're in, you can't get out. If you're out, you can't get in.

Answer (score 1):

The term "lockdown", in it current most common sense, derives from its use in prisons, where, during a "lockdown", prisoners are confined to their cells rather than being allowed to mingle in common areas.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockdown#Prisons):

> In its most common usage in corrections units, the term *lockdown* can
>   be defined as a course of action to control the movement of inmates.
>   Confining all prisoners, except workers, to their cells until the end
>   of the day is an example of a "lockdown period" in a corrections
>   schedule. However a "full lockdown" is used when all
>   prisoners are locked in their cells to prevent prison riots or unrest
>   from spreading or during an emergency.

The meaning of the term has been broadened to encompass, eg, the situation where a school may have its doors locked and students confined to classrooms during an "active shooter" event or some such.

The term is used somewhat figuratively when describing a "shelter at home" order, since doors are not locked (in the US, at least) and limited entry/exit is permitted.